# How ftp_nb_put store file in sub directory on server?

Tags: php

I success using php ftp_nb_put but the file will be store on home directory, does it possible to store file in sub directory by using php ftp_nb_put?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes why not ?

Try like this...

```
<?php
$conn_est = ftp_connect("*****") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn_est,"*****","*****");
ftp_nb_put($conn_est,"/home/www/folder/subfolder/file.jpg","yourlocalfile.jpg",FTP_BINARY);
//                     _____^^^^^^____ Is the remote location.      
ftp_close($conn_est);
```

The second parameter is where you want to put your local file to the remote location. Change that accordingly.